# Send Message to All users except one on Microsoft Windows 2012 Server

Tags: windows, batch-file

We have a Microsoft Windows 2012 Server on which we run updates automatically at fixed intervals of time. We want to display a message to the logged in users,give them a few minutes and then later log them out. We are using an internal automation tool.

I have found a batch file online which will send a message to all users and then later log them out. This works fine, except that we don't want the message to be displayed to one particular user, say "userX".
Below is the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
choice /T:60/D N /N > Nul
msg * You will be disconnected in 1 minute! Please log off now!
choice /T:60 /D N /N > Nul
query session >C:\SchedTasks\sessions.txt
find /v "userX" C:\SchedTasks\sessions.txt > C:\SchedTasks\killts.txt
for /f "skip=5 tokens=3," %%i in (C:\SchedTasks\killts.txt) DO logoff %%i
query session >C:\SchedTasks\sessions.txt
find /v "userX" C:\SchedTasks\sessions.txt > C:\SchedTasks\killts.txt
for /f "skip=5 tokens=2," %%i in (C:\SchedTasks\killts.txt) DO reset session       %%i
del C:\SchedTasks\sessions.txt
del C:\SchedTasks\killts.txt
EXIT
```

The automation tool launches command prompt, navigates to the location of the batch files and then executes the batch file.

How can I prevent the message from being sent to userX?

Comment: Will userX also be logged out and just not informed, or will userX stay logged in?

Comment: UserX will not be logged out neither receive the message

Comment: The script posted above will log off all users except UserX. This functionality is working fine but we dont want the messaage to be sent to userX. At the same time we don't know how many users or which users will be logged in the machine at the time. So everything needs to be dynamic.

Comment: would you accept a vbscript and batch hybrid?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using explicitly batch, consider the use of a vbscript (a .vbs file if you will) and batch hybrid. The reason for this is that vbscripts have a method of calling values straight from the registry that normal batch files do not. Vbscripts can be called and utilized within batch programs and the two can pass variables between each other.

```
set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
bing = wshShell.regread("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\USERNAME")
If bing <> "userX" Then
WScript.echo("Log Out Incoming")
End If
```

This code will search the registry of the current computer and determine if your user is the userX which if it is, will not display the log out message. If you wish to use this and to pass the logout message from your batch file, simply call from the batch script `cscript //nologo {DRIVE LETTER}:\filelocation %arg1%`. You can pass as many arguments as you want to the vbscript and from the script it will be referenced as `%1` `%2` and so forth for however many arguments.

The registry value may be different as your working on a network so i have no idea how that affects the registry of your computers. To see what that is, search for `regedit` on your machine and determine it for yourself. The registry contains all of the inner workings of your computer so work with caution and patience as its library's are immense and difficult to traverse if you do not know what you are looking for.